# magento routin url's

Tags: magento

I hav just started magento development. So, as a first step, I installed two copies of magento , separated by the root names only in my /var/www directory. Also, i have used sample data from magento's website.

Now, I did some simple module development in one of the magento installations, say, magento1, and when i moved to the other installation of magento, magento2, cleaning up the database also, I'm not able to load that new magento url in browser. Something is redirecting me to previous magento installation directory(magento1).

Why is this happening ? And, what is the solution  to this?

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Are you using the same database, because the BASE URL may be redirecting you back to the default store?

Comment: i changed base url to peropr path by phpmyadmin....but still no luck!

Comment: Ok, it worked!. I just needed to flush the cache by cleaning everything under var/cache directory. Thanx for ur help......

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to do it as Menno suggested + cleaning the cache as i mentioned in the comment..